# how to get tr using html agility pack

Tags: html, parsing, html-agility-pack

The html is like this

```
<tr>
<th class="label">Brand</th>
<td class="data">Dell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Series</th>
<td class="data">Inspiron Touch</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Color</th>
<td class="data">Black & Red</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Operating System</th>
<td class="data">Windows 10 Home</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Screen Size</th>
<td class="data">15.6"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Touchscreen</th>
<td class="data">Yes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Screen Resolution</th>
<td class="data">3840 x 2160</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Processor Type</th>
<td class="data">Intel Core i7 6th Gen</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Processor Speed</th>
<td class="data">2.6 GHz</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Processor Turbo</th>
<td class="data">Up to 3.5 GHz</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Processor Cache</th>
<td class="data">6 MB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Processor Model</th>
<td class="data">i7-6700HQ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">RAM</th>
<td class="data">16GB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">RAM Type</th>
<td class="data">DDR3L</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Hard Disk Capacity</th>
<td class="data">1TB + 128GB SSD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">HDD Interface</th>
<td class="data">SATA, SSD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">HDD RPM</th>
<td class="data">5400</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Graphics</th>
<td class="data">Nvidia Graphics</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="label">Graphics Detail</th>
<td class="data">Nvidia GeForce GTX 960M</td>
</tr>
```

i want to get label and data of every th and td tag inside tr tag, first 4 only Brand series color and Operating system, but there are some other items too having same th and td class inside a tr, please tell me how to get these items using html agility pack, i am inserting these 4 into DB, i used select nodes i am getting inner text of first tr only, when i for when i reach on these tr's i am using this code

```
 HtmlNodeCollection specsNode = null;
            specsNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr']");
            foreach (HtmlNode node in specsNode)
            {
                string htmli = node.InnerHtml;
                HtmlDocument doci = new HtmlDocument();
                doci.LoadHtml(htmli); 
    htmlNode node2 in doci.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='data']"){
node2.InnerText;
```

i am familier with HAP much more now but the classes inside tr are same and i don't know how to get them now.

Comment: Post sample HTMl that include *some other items too having same th and td class inside a tr*. Also, what have you tried so far using HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: @har07 i have edited the question

Comment: @har07 as every th td has same class so select method every time select first th and td i don't know how to get second third and fourth

Comment: 1. Your code didn't compile, so it is hard to see what you're trying to do *exactly*. 2. `SelectNodes()` should return *all* matching nodes, not only the first matched. So what's the problem actually?

Comment: yeah i know double slash and a tag will give me all matching node but i want only first 4, and insert them into my DB after i just want first four but it is selecting all of them as the classes are same, of is there i way i can manipulate and give them different class names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what are you're trying to do here but I guess the `.Contains` function may help you in solving your problem, use `.Contains` function for checks

```
string Result=html;
htmldocument doc=new htmldocument();
doc.Loadhtml(Result);
htmlnodecollection noden=null;
noden=doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("");
if(Result.Contains("your brand")==true)
{
//do something
```